# How to change parameter in javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript

I want to change the title parameter in javascript dynamically based upon conditions . This script is used as common across many page. so whenever i use this script i need to append new title based on conditions. I have highlighted title in bold.

How can do this. In below example Logging Out is my title

```
var t = setTimeout("javascript:OpenLogoffDialog('/RPS/Common/TimeOut.aspx', 380, 160, 'Logging out...', false, false);", 180000); // 17 min
```

Comment: you mean `title` of the HTML page?

Comment: Yes its asp.net page but this script opens a dialog box of the page

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to just target the title DOM node like this:

```
var title = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
title.textContent = 'Your new title';
```

You will have to use `innerText` in some browsers, but I think this may be a more straightforward approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the call with a function in the scope of some context variables and then call the `OpenLogoffDialog` manually:

```
(function () {
    //obviously not all of these are necessary...
    var page = '/RPS/Common/TimeOut.aspx';
    var width = 380;
    var height = 160;
    var title = "Logging out...";
    var param1 = false;
    var param2 = false;

    //code...


    var t = setTimeout(function () {
        OpenLogoffDialog(page, width, height, title, param1, param2);
    }, 180000);

    //more stuff...


})()
```

Now you can change those variables as desired inside of the IIFE scope and the `OpenLogoffDialog` function will be called with whatever theyre set to.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myTitle;

if(userIsLogginOut == true){
    myTitle = 'Logging Out...';
}else{
    myTitle = 'Other Title';
}

var t = setTimeout(function(){
    OpenLogoffDialog('/RPS/Common/TimeOut.aspx', 380, 160, myTitle, false, false);
}, 180000);
```